# How can I delete multiple keywords from a column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm running

```
UPDATE mytable SET FruitsColumn = REPLACE(FruitsColumn,'apple','')
```

it works fine and deletes every instance of the word "apple" from my column.

But how would I delete apple, and also other words at the same time?

I tried

```
UPDATE mytable SET FruitsColumn = REPLACE(FruitsColumn,'apple,orange,strawberry','')
```

and it wouldnt work

Comment: Normalize your data saved the proper way and these nightmares will not be yours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to do nested REPLACE calls:

```
UPDATE mytable SET FruitsColumn =
REPLACE(REPLACE(FruitsColumn,'orange',''),'apple','')
```